# How to deploy Django app on Ubuntu when using Gitlab

Tags: django, git, gitlab

I have create a simple Django application, then I have commit and push to Gitlab. Finally I would like to install that application on my "production server" which is running ubuntu so from that server terminal I run the command:

```
git clone https://domain.com/path/to/git
```

I cannot find my python code among the file cloned.

What is the correct way to get the python code from the gitlab repository?

Comment: Please provide a list of the files cloned so we can tell what actually got pulled down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the branch, I solve choosing a specific branch, applying the option "-b" followed by the proper branch name "develop":

```
git clone -b develop https://example.com/username/projectname.git
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

does your git has all source code including the pip installed apps?

- If yes: install the django version on your ubuntu machine, clone your project and possibly it will run.
- If no: you must create a [virtual enviroment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) (which is a recommended option in any case), install all the pip installed apps **AND** django inside the virtual enviroment. After that clone your project and it will run.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know about gitlab, and there's basically everything missing about your configuration on the server, but you can set up a git hook on a git repo.

here is and example of a post-receive hook to deploy an example django project.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    if [[ $ref =~ .*/master$ ]];
    then
        echo "master branch received, deploying..."
        GIT_WORK_TREE="/PATH/TO/DJANGO/PROJECT" git checkout -f master > /dev/null

        source /PATH/TO/DJANGO/VIRTUAL/ENVIRONMENT/bin/activate > /dev/null
        echo "installing new pip dependencies..."
        pip install -r /PATH/TO/DJANGO/PROJECT/dependencies.txt > /dev/null
        echo "applaying new db migrations..."
        python /PATH/TO/DJANGO/PROJECT/manage.py migrate_schemas > /dev/null
        deactivate > /dev/null

        touch /PATH/TO/DJANGO/PROJECT/PROJECT_NAME/wsgi.py > /dev/null
        echo "Sever code reloaded."
    else
        echo "Received branch $ref, not deploying."
    fi
done
```

so a few thing to consider:

- This script is located on gitrepo.git/hooks/post-recive
- The file post-recive must be executable `chmod +x FILE_NAME`
- It assumes you have a virtual environment.
- It assumes you have a file on the repo called dependencies.txt, you can generate it with `pip freeze > dependencies.txt` (note, everything on the file will be insatled on the server)
- Note `touch wsgi.py` would reload the code if your running apache with mod_wsgi on daemon mode ([more info](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ReloadingSourceCode.wiki))